# URL Rewrite of Non-Existent File Under Subdomain Folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

My website structure is as follows:

```
.htaccess
index.html
internal
   .htaccess
   test.html
   api.php
```

I have setup a subdomain in GoDaddy such that `internal.ledworld-me.com` maps to `ledworld-me.com/internal` and the following works fine:

Requesting `internal.ledworld-me.com/test.html` serves the `test.html` file correctly.

Now I need the following:

If `internal.ledworld-me.com/nonexistent/file` is requested, then the URL should be rewritten as `ledworld-me.com/internal/api.php?__route__=/nonexistent/file`.

What do I put in my `.htaccess` file in order to achieve this? And which `.htaccess` file should I put the code in, the one under `WebRoot` or the one under `internal`?

Please note that GoDaddy is taking care of the rewriting from `internal.ledworld-me.com` to `ledworld-me.com/internal`. All I need my `.htaccess` file to do is the second part of the rewrite, namely, `/nonexistent/file` should be rewritten as `api.php?__route__=/nonexistent/file`.

It's really hard to explain this question and I've tried my best, please ask for clarification if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your **`/internal/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ api.php?__route__=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This gives a 404 not found with the message "The requested URL /internal/nonexistent/file was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

The following text in my internal/.htaccess file seems to do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on                                                                          
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                       
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ledworld-me.com/internal/api.php?__route__=/$1
```

I'm still testing all the scenarios and will confirm that everything is working once I'm done all the tests.